# Sortable not working with different height columns

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with this library: [HTML5 Sortable Drag and Drop](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/).

I am using it for blocks, 2 columns wide. The markup for it:

```
<ul class="sortable grid">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li style="height: 200px;">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li style="height: 200px;">Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

I am having an issue though. When certain blocks have different heights, I need to somehow clear the `float` after the 2nd block so that it does not mess up the layout.

[image: bad]

There is a live working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/4njSE/6/ , if anyone has any ideas. I have tried doing `.sortable>:nth-child(odd) {clear:left}` with the selector on the Odd `li` list items and this works appearance wise, but it messes up the functionality of the drag and drop, when you drop items they will not go into the correct position when I do that.

This JSFiddle shows it working with the `.sortable>:nth-child(odd) {clear:left}` added  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/4njSE/7/

And ideas? I am at a loss right now.

I have also tried wrapping every set of 2 blocks inside there own container which helps but then the drag and drop does not work correctly as the library adds a `dragable` to the container divs.

This is an image of the goal, of how it should look:

[image: good]

Comment: Where is the "live working demo"?

Comment: @OpherV Sorry here is the one that does not work like in the bad image  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/4njSE/6/  and this one looks "right" using `.sortable>:nth-child(odd) {clear:left}` but does not work very wel as far as the drag and drop positions  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/4njSE/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

First - the [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/7jur6/#base).

Basically, I've added two event callbacks to the plugin: `onStartDrag` and `onEndDrag`. These in turn call the `addFloats` function, a simple function that takes care of adding floats to odd elements that *aren't* the `sortable-dragging` element (This can't be achieved with pure CSS). We also had to call that function when calling the sortable plugin, but that's about it.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hey thanks you so much, that is a step closer to how I want it.  As you probably noticed it still has a weird behavior, I think it would work better if the placeholder class would have the same height as the box being moved.  Inside the JS I saw that it has a section with I thought it was supposed to do that but apparently that doesn't work in the default code.  Would you happen to know how to fix that as well?  Appreciate your contributions either way thank you!

Comment: Done. Take a look at `placeholder.css("height",$(this).height()+"px");`

Comment: Hey you are amazing, very kind of you to help me I am more of a PHP coder.  If you start out with this position http://codedevelopr.com/screenshots/2013-03-18_16-34-40.png
 and then move  Item 3 to the right column like this 
http://codedevelopr.com/screenshots/2013-03-18_16-35-52.png
instead of the placeholder showing in the right column it shows in the left column..just a weird issue.  I'm not sure this is even fixable the way this code works.  I don't expect you to fix it all but maybe you can tell me if it's even possible.  Thanks so much for your help, marking your answer as the best

Comment: Glad to help! Sure, I've added another handler `onChangeOrder` that calls the same method: `onChangeOrder: function(){addFloats($(".sortable"))} `. This way, every time the order is changed mid-drag, the floats get sorted out as well. Does this work out for you?

Comment: Hello, this adds it even closer to being perfect, really amazing work, its a shame I can't keep up-voting this over and over lol.  It is not PERFECT, has a couple glitches here and there due to the different sized blocks but this I believe is much better then what I started out with, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS:

```
.sortable>:nth-child(odd) {clear:left}
```

Comment: Hello I had tried this but it messes up the drag/drop functionality order